# Web app - How do I connect two different pages with firebase?

Tags: html, firebase, web

I am in the process of creating a quiz web app for university. I've decided to use firebase as I've heard good things about it. I've managed to get hosting working, however I'm having trouble with a few other things.

First of all, I'm using HTML, CSS, JS and a little bit of JQUERY.

The idea of the quiz is to have a host view, which would be a teacher putting it on a projector and to then have student views which would be the student connecting on their phones.

The host view allows for the teacher to select the question on their computer, and then that question gets pushed towards the students phones. Once the student answers the question a boolean gets pushed back to the host view to tell them if they got it right or wrong.

At the moment I've only got the student view being hosted and I can't figure out the best way of doing this through firebase. My inital thought was to get a database set up between them both. However, I'm unsure on how to go about that. Would it be better if they were both hosted under one domain and once on that domain the user gets the option of selecting HOST/VIEW?

I'd appreciate any help given web development isn't my strong suit.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Given that we're talking about code, pretty much anything can be made to work. If you put both views into a single page+JavaScript, then you're creating what is known as a single-page application (a great term to search on for more information). If you keep them separate, you have a more traditional model. If both views are mostly the same, I'd probably start with a single-page application. If they are not very similar, I'd start with a separate page+script for each view. But this is very much my preference, and no hard rule.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the answer, I was wondering how to do it with firebase however.

Comment: First make it work without Firebase, then add Firebase. That's in general the recommended approach for building complex software: create the smallest functional part of it, then add another part, and another, until you have the app you want to ship. If you get stuck, show the [minimal code/steps that are needed to reproduce where got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you want to build web software on Firebase, I recommend taking the codelab for web developers: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/